# Manually changing form/textarea input with javascript and making sure all event listeners are fired

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Working on a project where I need to manually fill in input fields and textareas on various random websites. So far I've been doing "element.value = 'new value'" alongside "element.innerHTML = 'new value'", but for some websites there seem to be event listeners that aren't getting called when I do this.

So I figured I'd better call these manually, and added "element.onchange()" and a bunch of others (onkeypress, onkeydown, onkeyup), and also tried passing in the element into the function "element.onchange(element)". But neither of these seem to work for many websites.

As an example, go to http://www.facebook.com (logged out) and run:

```
javascript:var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('inputtext'); for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { var element = elements[i]; element.value = 'New Test Value'; element.innerHTML = 'New Test Value'; element.onkeypress; };
```

You should see all input boxes change value to "New Test Value", but the placeholder text is still in place (belongs to a different element). When you click on a input box on the page manually some function is getting called that removes this if there's text in the box.

So how do I make sure that any event listener attached to the element always gets called just as it does when we change value manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
 var isCreatEvent = "createEvent" in document, 
     allEles = document.querySelectorAll('input'); // collect required elements.

 for(var i = 0; i < allEles.length; i++){
  var element = allEles[i];
  element.onchange();
  if (isCreatEvent) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
  else
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
 }
```

Comment: I tried doing that as well, but doesn't seem to have any effect.